# SAP Cloud Foundry Trial and hanatrial Service HDI-Shared Plan

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

I'm using a trial account in *SAP Cloud Platform* and created an instance of the "**hanatrial**" service, witch is up and I can even query the public table  "tables".

The service provide me, in the `VCAP_SERVICES`, two users: *user* and *hdi_user*.
Both appears to have the same privileges in the schema provided, and cannot create any data in any public table table nor create any tables inside the provided schema.

My question is: is it possible to create tables or a single table with the "hanatrial" service? I have been two days searching for an answer in the SAP documentation and in the Internet without having found an evidence that it is nor that it is not.

Comment: I also stuck with the same thing. If you have solved it, it would be really helpful if can you share it over here. Thanks

Comment: Well, the issue took too long and my boss said to let it go. As far as I could learn you should give it up too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you whom still wonder apparently Hanatrial has no suport for creating tables.